# Which createReadStream am I calling here?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jestjs

I'm trying to mock a call to S3 using the `aws-sdk-mock` package. I want to mock getObject on a bucket, so that instead of `createReadStream()` creating a network stream from a bucket, it creates a readable stream from a local file in my test suite.

Here's how I'm mocking the s3 call:

```
s3Spy = AWS.mock("S3", "getObject", {
    createReadStream: () => {
        return fs.createReadStream(testDataFile)
    }
});
```

Here's the line where it is used:

```
const stream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
```

I can trace `stream` with a console.log call, and it's clearly a readable:

```
console.log(stream)
Readable {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    ...
  },
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _read: [Function (anonymous)],
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

However, if I inspect it further, it's not a file readable:

```
console.log(stream.path)
undefined
```

Which `createReadStream` am I calling if it's not the one in my mock? How can I write this so that I pull in the mocked data that I want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the mocking code:

```
s3Spy = AWS.mock("S3", "getObject", fs.createReadStream(testDataFile));
```